# Inserting a 0 into field

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to update a database using a PDO function but the password will update yet the username, name will not but the name is updating with a 0 instead of the content I change it too?

```
public function insert($table, $fields = array()){  

    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $values .="?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';    
        }
        $x++;
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and showing the data here:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->update('users', 1, array(
        password => 'erwrwe',
        name => 'Dan'
));
```

Comment: Can you clarify your issue? It is hard to understand what you are describing. Is the username changing to 0 when you only want the password changed?

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain properly, so I want to change the fields for username, password and name but if I make a change to the users details the password changes, the username dosnt change but the name changes to a 0 in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays start at 0, while you're starting your array count at `$x = 1`, which means you're suffering from a fencepost error (aka "off-by-one").

Change your code to

```
    if($x <= count($fields)) {
           ^---
```

or start with `$x = 0` instead.

---

comment followup: Look at what your code is doing:

$fields = array('name' => 'foo', 'password' => 'bar');

An array with two items, so `count($files)` is `2`

```
$x = 1;
foreach($fields as $field) {
    if ($x < count(fields) { ... }
}
```

On the first iteration:

```
field -> name, $x -> 1, count -> 2
    $x < count   --> 1 < 2  --> TRUE
       ... add a ?
       $x++
```

On the second iteration:

```
field -> password, $x -> 2, count -> 2
    $x < count  --> 2 < 2 --> FALSE
```

loop aborts, and you only end up with ONE `?` in your `$values` list.

For your three item test, you successfully handle $x=1 and $x=2, but then the loop aborts on the 3rd item, because `$x < 3` is FALSE.

So yes, it's an off-by-one error. If you have `$x <= 3` or started $x with `0` then you'd properly process that last item in the array.

Comment: Something very bizarre is happening if I add all three inserts so username, password and name two will populate but the third will set to 0

Comment: it's not "the third", it's n-1. you set things up for n-1 entries, but have n entries to the last one is always dropped.

Comment: So how where am I going wrong because if I have just place name and password in there depending on the order it only inserts first one. I tried your suggestion but that didn't clear up the error.

Comment: I already TOLD you where you're going wrong. `<=` v.s. `<`. see my comment followup above.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc B answer. If you're inserting text into the database you need quotes around you values:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ('{$values}')";
```

Comment: Something very bizarre is happening if I add all three inserts so username, password and name two will populate but the third will set to 0

Comment: Your third value isn't being evaluated.

Comment: But if I take the third away it only evaluates one...? Also, If I change the order they evaluate differently too

Comment: $values is something like `?,?,?`. OP is setting up placeholders. adding quotes will disable the placeholders and really muck things up